# Cannot do sum in lisp with do loop

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun suma (L)
  (setq var 0)
  (do 
      ((i 0 (+ i 1)))
      ((= i (length L)))
    (+ var (nth i L)))
  var)
```

Why does it always returns 0?

Shouldn't it return sum of list L?

Comment: Please start with getting a good editor which will indent the code for you.

Comment: you should bind `var` with `let` instead of making it global with `setq`

Comment: i get same result with let...and im using notepad++ but posted code without indent sry

Comment: the problem with `setq` is that you are creating a global variable. you should not do that in functions.

Answer (score 2):

[`+`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_pl.htm) does not modify its arguments, so, since you never modify `var`, its initial value of 0 is returned.

You need to replace `(+ var (nth i L))` with `(incf var (nth i L))`, of, equivalently, `(setq var (+ var (nth i L)))`.

See [`incf`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_incf_.htm).

Note that you should bind `var` with [`let`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_let_l.htm) instead of making it global with [`setq`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_setq.htm).

Most importantly, note that your algorithm is *quadratic* in the length of the list argument (because [`nth`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nth.htm) scans your list every time from the start).

Here are some better implementations:

```
(defun sum-1 (l)
  (reduce #'+ l))

(defun sum-2 (l)
  (loop for x in l sum x))

(defun sum-3 (l)
  (let ((sum 0))
    (dolist (x l sum)
      (incf sum x))))
```

Here is a *bad* implementation:

```
(defun sum-4 (l)
  (apply #'+ l))
```

The problem with `sum-4` is that it will fail if the length of the supplied list is larger than [`call-arguments-limit`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_call_a.htm).

Comment: I did bind var with let and put incf but get same result which is 0. I checked loop and it does its job but when i'm adding to var it puts 0 and i cant understand why. But when i print ( nth i L ) it prints element of list at index i.

Comment: Please add your new code to the end of your question. Please make sure it is properly formatted, as we Lispers parse code by indentation, not by paren counting (which should be done by editors, not humans).

Answer (score 0):

I thought this would be a comment for the full learning experience, but I was not able to put code in the comment.

There is a way to do sums without modifying any argument, and that is by doing it recursively:

```
(defun recsum (list)
  (if list
      (+ (first list) (recsum (rest list)))
      0))
```

This version can be tail call optimized by the compiler, and as fast as a loop:

```
(defun recsum2 (list &optional (accumulator 0))
  (if list
      (recsum2 (rest list) (+ accumulator (first list)))
      accumulator))
```

What you are trying to do could be done with `do` like this:

```
(defun suma (l)
  (do 
   ((var 0)
    (i 0 (+ i 1)))
   ((= i (length l)) var)
    (incf var (nth i l))))
```

But we don't usually do anything in `do`s body, so it's like this then:

```
(defun suma (l)
  (do
   ((i 0 (+ i 1))
    (var 0 (+ var (nth i l))))
   ((= i (length l)) var)))
```

But `nth` and `length` are slow, so better do it this way:

```
(defun suma (l)
  (do* 
   ((var (first l) (+ var (first list)))
    (list (rest l) (rest list)))
   ((null list) var)))
```

This one is without the `*` in `do`, and returns 0 on empty list:

```
(defun suma (l)
  (do 
   ((acc 0 (+ acc (first list)))
    (list l (rest list)))
   ((null list) acc)))
```

But my favorite is the `reduce` version from @sds which also can return 0 on empty list with :initial-value 0

EDIT: recsum2 did not return anything, so it needed a fix.

Comment: If "all" I want to do is sum a list, in Common Lisp, I'd probably use `(loop for v in the-list sum v)`