# Sum of rows in a matrix with lisp

Tags: matrix, sum, lisp, row, apply

I'm doing some LISP exercises using functions `mapcar` and `apply`. I'm dealing with matrixes, and I have to sum its rows and columns. For column I have:

```
(apply #'mapcar #'+ matrix)
```

That works. Since I know how to transpose a matrix, I can do the exact same thing for the rows right? Right, that would be:

```
(apply #'mapcar #'+ (apply #'mapcar #'list matrix))
```

**But I'm not happy** **with that**. I want to sum the row directly, so I did a `mapcar` of `apply`:

```
(mapcar #'apply #'+ matrix)
```

that **doesn't** work and I don't know why. The error is

> The value #(FUNCTION +) is not of type LIST.
>      [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]

For me, that would get every list inside matrix, and apply the sum in each one. I cannot make a `mapcar` of `apply`? If no, why not? Is there another way to sum the rows of a matrix using just `mapcar` and `apply`?

PS: I'm using lispstick to compile and the matrix is a list of lists. Example

```
((1 1 1) (2 2 2) (3 3 3))
```

for a 3x3 matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your error

The error you got is from [`mapcar`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mapc_.htm) which expects lists as its arguments after the 1st one, and finds the function [`+`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_pl.htm) instead.

## Solution

What you need is a partial application of [`apply`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apply.htm) to `+`, i.e.,

```
(defparameter matrix '((1 1 1) (2 2 2) (3 3 3)))
(mapcar (lambda (l) (apply #'+ l)) matrix)
==> (3 6 9)
```

You can even define a function for that:

```
(defun partial-application (f &rest some-args)
  (lambda (&rest more-args)
    (apply f (append some-args more-args))))
(funcall (partial-application #'+ 4) 5)
==> 9
(funcall (partial-application #'+ 1 2) 3 4 5)
==> 15
```

Now you can use it instead of the [`lambda`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_lambda.htm):

```
(mapcar (partial-application #'apply #'+) matrix)
==> (3 6 9)
```

## Notes:

1. `(lambda (l) (apply #'+ l))` and `(partial-application #'apply #'+)` merely compute the sum of a list, and can be defined in many different ways as discussed [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41067087/850781).
2. [`append`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_append.htm) **cannot** be safely replaced with the non-consing verson [`nconc`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nconc.htm) because `some-args` [is not guaranteed to be *fresh*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_dac.htm):

> The value of a rest parameter is permitted, but not required, to share structure with the last argument to `apply`.

Comment: I'm feeling one might make something like `(defun applyfun (fn) (lambda (lst) (apply fn lst))` but I'm not convinced the name is right.

Comment: @Sylwester: yep, added `partial-application`, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You could generalize this into a full currying function with `(defun curry (f &rest args) (lambda (&rest more-args) (apply f (append args more-args))))`